# Проверить наличие определённого значения элемента многомерного массива по ключу

Tags: php

Доброе время суток, есть массив $categories

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [category_id] => 1 
    [item_id] => 63 
    [qualification_category_id] => 0
  ) 
  [1] => Array (
    [category_id] => 3 
    [item_id] => 63 
    [qualification_category_id] => 1 
  ) 
  [2] => Array (
    [category_id] => 4 
    [item_id] => 63
    [qualification_category_id] => 0 
  )
)
```

и есть id категории, ее нужно проверить на существование в массиве...
2 дня мучаюсь эффекта 0

```
if (array_key_exists('2', $categories)) {   
    $json['isset '] = true;
} else {
    $json['isset '] = false;
}
```

Вот этот вариант почему то не сработал (

Answer (score 3):

> array_key_exists() ищет ключи только на первом уровне массива. Внутренние ключи в многомерных массивах найдены не будут. [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-key-exists.php)

```
$json['isset'] = in_array('2', array_column($doctor_categories, 'doctor_category_id')); // true 1/false 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function hasEqualProp($array, $prop, $value) {
  foreach ($array as $subarr) {
    if (isset($subarr[$prop]) and $subarr[$prop] == $value) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

-----

if (hasEqualProp($doctor_categories, 'doctor_category_id', '2')) {    
  echo 'found';
} else {
  echo 'not found';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
<?php
$search_category_id = 2;

$found = array_filter($doctor_categories, function($doctor) use ($search_category_id){
  return $doctor["doctor_category_id"] == $search_category_id;
});

$has_category = !empty($found); // true - есть, false - нету
print_r($found); // Все у кого категория = 2
```

Comment: какой смысл фильтровать массив и создавать новый, если требуется только установить сам факт наличия нужного id. Вам по сути от этой фильтрации нужен только факт первого совпадения, а результат не нужен вовсе.

Comment: @teran, а вдруг пригодится =)

Comment: @teran, а так то согласен, вы правы